# Select first free number

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

Hello I've got a table like this:

```
scheme.tabname
(
id integer not null default nextval('my_seq'::regclass),
lp integer not null
);
```

And I want `lp` to be the first free number starting from zero. Every new year it's starting over from zero.

I'd prefer it to be some `SELECT` so I can put it directly into my code.
Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Assuming `nextval()` and `nextcal` was a typo - orthogonal to the problem either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found easy way to find first free number in each year.

```
select case count(filter.lp) when 0 then 1
else min(filter.lp) end as lp

from (SELECT  lp + 1 as lp
FROM    table mo
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    table mi 
        WHERE   mi.lp= mo.lp + 1 and Extract(year from  mi.data_rejestracji) = Extract(year from Now())
    )
ORDER BY
    lp
LIMIT 1) filter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(lp) + 1 FROM shceme.tablename
```

will get you the next lp but to start over each year you would need a column with year in it.

Comment: This doesn't work when concurrent processes are requesting a new number, unless you lock the table for other readers.

Comment: It wont work beacuse what if I delete some number in a middle? 
I need to use it again.